# how to texture a head model using exsiting images?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Im pretty new with blender, and desperate with failing again and again with what Im trying to do. I hope this question is not a duplicate and can use others as well:

I've created a model using a scanner and imported it into blender.
I have side and front photos of the man scanned.
My goal is to texture the head using the photos, creating a high detailed photo-realistic texture that can be UV-unmapped and printed as one or two unwrapped photo islands.

I've watched a few tutorials using a range of tools like bprojection, project painting, cloning etc., but for some reason I couldn't follow them and succeed- every time the process went wrong followed by horrific results esthetically. I've read that bprojection is replaced by a tool called stencil brush but I couldn't find it.
The web offers so many tools that doesn't work for me!

To make a long story short, what is the best way to create a photo realistic texture for the head?
thank you!
[image: the model and a part of the side-image]

Comment: The red lines that you have in your model are seams?

Comment: This can be done with stencil texture painting... an example is this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gacSqM7kHGg or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw3etcjL47o

Comment: the red lines are seams. I will check the video, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoiYMx2xXGA

A few suggestions (since you are new): While in object mode on the *Tools Shelf* (open with <kbd>T</kbd> key) select  *Smooth* under *Shading*. I'm assuming you don't want flat shading for a head :).

For hair I recommend Particle System based solution, if the model isn't being created for a game.

If you use your picture for hair it will probably look like these old 3d models in Playstation 2 , remember the flatness?

But there are some techniques for hair that are pretty good although made with pictures.

For any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I think this won't work well (or it will be too hard to work with) with his model because the topology isn't arranged well in his model.

Comment: xlxs, you are so very much correct. this model sucks and makes my work harder a 100 times more. anyway, thank you Chris.

Comment: xlxs: you can give it a try though . D Brown: no problem .